# ALSA error messages pyaudio

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.4, alsa, pyaudio

Have some ALSA error messages. Everything work well, but it bothers me. I'm using pyAudio 0.2.9, Ubuntu 15.10 x64, python3.4. Is any solutions to ignore this?

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1024:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1024:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
```

other error

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:614:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
```

Comment: These messages can be ignored.

Comment: The [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/) module suppresses those messages